# Trying to print a session variable in a jsp causes error "equals expected"

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to pass a value from the session object to a custom tag `<l:LoginStatus userId="<% out.print((String)session.getAttribute("userId")); %>"/>`

Why does this line give me the error: 
*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(1,1) /header.jsp(64,131) equal symbol expected*

When I pass a hard coded value like this `<l:LoginStatus userId="4"/>`

Everything works fine.

It doesn't make any sense to me, I thought using `out.print` would make `=` uneccessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to just use [EL](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html). That yields much cleaner code.

```
<l:LoginStatus userId="${userId}" />
```

Comment: Thankyou, that solved the problem noted and another problem with ClassCastExceptions that I was getting using the method I was trying.

Comment: CCE can occur when the object is *actually* not a `String` at all. After all, casting is unnecessary here. The `<%= %>` would implicitly call `String#valueOf()` on it. So `<%= session.getAttribute("userId") %>` would also just have worked. Using *scriptlets* is however [discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files).

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
<%= (String)session.getAttribute("userId") %>
```

In general it is much better practice to do things this way, instead of writing directly to a page.  Besides, things don't work exactly as you seem to think they do.

Comment: Your last statement is technically wrong. It's the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

As you're printing the value of the an expression, you should make the statement as

```
<l:LoginStatus userId="<%=out.print((String)session.getAttribute("userId"))%>"/>
```

or

```
<l:LoginStatus userId="<%=out.print(session.getAttribute("userId")).toString()%>"/>
```

Comment: The `<%= x %>` does effectively the same as `<% out.print(x) %>`. So this answer is wrong.